# Convert number to characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a system where users must write userid:s into their phone. I want to obfuscate the id:s so that it is fairly hard to guess the number and then I want to convert it into a base-23 number using the following characters:

```
abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz
```

I'm droppin I,L and O, because those characters seriously suck in id-numbers.

So forexample if the input is `23`, the output would be `aa`, `24` would be `ab` etc. (I will scramble/unscramble the userIds before I run them through this function)

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the integer into a letter. this is the best I can com up with:

```
var scrambled = 234,
    charmap = ['a','b','c'...]

scrambled.toString(23)
```

Here I would like to do charmap[scrambled] for every single character and save it to a string, I could convert the scrambled to a string and split it, but I think there is a cleaner way of doing it. Modern web tech is ok!

Comment: can you share some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Exactly, because we can't catch your goal

Comment: updated with two examples, let me know if it's still not clear!

Comment: Side note, did you intend to be declaring charmap? Multiple vars should be separated by comma where you have a semi-colon. You could be unintentionally polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @Mvarta typo, thanks!

Comment: @Himmator got your back dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your charmap is not trivial, you could instead write your own function. 
With the charmap hidden in a closure.

Here is a complete fiddle, provinding two side conversion object:

```js
var convert = (function() {
  var base = 23;
  var charmap = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
  return {
    toString: function(i) {
      var result = "";
      do {
        result = charmap.charAt(i % base) + result;
        i = (i - i % base) / base;
      } while (i > 0);

      return result;
    },
    fromString: function(s) {
      var result = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
        var k = charmap.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
        result = result * base + k;
      }

      return result;
    }
  };
}());


for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  if (convert.fromString(convert.toString(i)) !== i) {
    console.log("error at " + i);
  }
}

console.log("ok");
```

Comment: This is smart, you are smart!

Comment: However, I need to do the reverse aswell, IE convert a string to a integer, suppose I could reverse that aswell

Comment: this also causes an infinit loop because i ends up at 0.

Comment: `convert.toString(23)` returns `"ab"`... instead of `"aa"`

Comment: Also... `9007199254740991234 ... toString != fromString` ;)

Comment: Also `021 toString === 21 toString` ;)

Comment: 23.toString(23) returns "10" which is the same as "ba". just a matter of ordering. for the second comment it's a precision loss in the division (which is performed in floating point in javascript). invoking toString(23) and a string replace would not reproduce the issue, but the OP didn't want that kind of solution

Comment: @RegisPortalez I think OP takes a numerical ID. Like a bank token, remember? It can start with `0`. If my token is say `0531` you cannot decode it to `345`. Hope it makes sense

Comment: I'm positive that OP takes that nID from an input element, `this.value` will always return a String, so I'd start my logic considering a *numerical* String :)

Comment: please provide your own answer instead of all those comments. OP will appreciate more

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan worth mentioning!, what properities of 9007199254740991234 make it not work?

Comment: @RegisPortalez really nice work if you ping me in two days, i'd love to give you some bounty!

Comment: @Himmators no, it'll not work cause it exceeds the expected Number length and gets exponents and runs into floating point precision issues. Also, a user ID like `"0531"` will get back-decoded incorrectly as `345` (due to the leading 0). I'd really like to post a solution but I was long waiting for more info on how you actually plan to convert `23` to `aa` and what's your logic behind that result. Currently I'm a bit busy. Though, would be helpful you provide more examples and all the possible caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, i have in C#, its doing the exact thing, and am sure you can convert it to Javascript:

```
private static string strBasechars = "BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  public static string ToBase(long input)
        {
            string r = string.Empty;
            int targetBase = strBasechars.Length;
            do
            {
                r = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                    strBasechars[(int)(input % targetBase)],
                    r);
                input /= targetBase;
            } while (input > 0);

            return r;
        }
```

Although i highly recommend you to remove the all the vowels as you might end up with some bad words :)

Comment: Cool I don't write C, one or two comments in the code would make it a lot easier for me to read :)

Comment: @Himmators ... check the 2nd answer posted by Regis Portalez ... its exactly what you need. 23 is targetBase in my sample ... everything else is the same

Answer (score 0):

You could use a do while loop for encoding and get the remainder of the value and the length of the character set for encoding and for decoding use a hash table and calculate the value upon the indices.

```js
function encode(value, charmap) {
    var encoded = '',
        l = charmap.length;

    do {
        encoded = charmap[value % l] + encoded;
        value = Math.floor(value / l);
    } while (value)
    return encoded;
}

function decode(value, charmap) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        l = charmap.length;

    charmap.split('').forEach(function (a, i) {
        hash[a] = i;
    });
    return value.split('').reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r * l + hash[a];
    }, 0);
}

var charmap = 'abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz',
    encodeValue = 23,
    encodedValue = encode(encodeValue, charmap),
    decodedValue = decode(encodedValue, charmap);

console.log(encodedValue);
console.log(decodedValue);
```